# chromedriver seems to be blocked

Tags: java, selenium-chromedriver

I am using chromedriver to automated crawling. When I invoke method like `findElements` or `switchTo().frame(frame)`, the program seems to be blocked, and the page in the browser looks normal, but there is nothing in the `Elements` tag of DevTools.

```
public class WebDoc {

    public static WebElement findElement(WebDriver driver, SearchContext context, By by) {
        List<WebElement> elements = findElements(driver, context, by);
        if (elements.isEmpty()) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("element not found: '%s'", by));
        }
        return elements.get(0);
    }

    public static List<WebElement> findElements(WebDriver driver, SearchContext context, By by) {
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ZERO);
        WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofMillis(4_000));
        wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(by));
        try {
            long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
            List<WebElement> elements = context.findElements(by);
            System.out.printf("spend: '%s ms', by: '%s'%n%n", (System.currentTimeMillis() - start), by);
            return elements;
        } finally {
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(Duration.ofMillis(30_000));
        }
    }

    public static void sleep(long millis) {
        try {
            Thread.sleep(millis);
        } catch (InterruptedException ignored) {
        }
    }

    public static WebDriver driver() {
        System.setProperty(ChromeDriverService.CHROME_DRIVER_EXE_PROPERTY, "/Users/xxx/chromedriver/chromedriver_117");
        ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
//        options.addArguments("--headless");
        options.addArguments("--incognito");
        options.addArguments("--no-sandbox");
        options.addArguments("--disable-gpu");
        options.addArguments("--disable-infobars");
        options.addArguments("--disable-extensions");
        options.addArguments("--window-size=1366,768");
        options.addArguments("--disable-dev-shm-usage");
        options.addArguments("--blink-settings=imagesEnabled=false");
        options.addArguments("--disable-blink-features=AutomationControlled");

        options.addArguments("--lang=zh-CN,zh,en");
        options.addArguments("--user-agent=Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/117.0.0.0 Safari/537.36");

        options.setExperimentalOption("useAutomationExtension", false);
        options.setExperimentalOption("excludeSwitches", new String[]{"enable-automation"});
        // i have tried other strategy and timeout values
        options.setPageLoadStrategy(PageLoadStrategy.NONE);
        options.setScriptTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30_000));
        options.setPageLoadTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(60_000));
        options.setImplicitWaitTimeout(Duration.ofMillis(30_000));
        ChromeDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(ChromeDriverService.createDefaultService(), options);
        return driver;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = driver();
        try {
            driver.get("https://music.163.com/#/song?id=17933856");
            // wait the website load complete
            sleep(10_000);
            // iframe#g_iframe; most spend time over 10s
            WebElement frame = findElement(driver, driver, By.tagName("iframe"));
            // the time spent is several times longer than the above
            driver.switchTo().frame(frame);
            // ... things i want to do
        } finally {
            driver.quit();
        }
    }

}
```

- OS: Apple M2 Pro
- JDK: 8
- chromedriver: 4.12.1
- chrome: 117

Is one or all of my options or usage wrong?